# adb recognizes my device but when i open eclipse connection is lost

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

I have managed to use my device (Chinese tablet named Pipo S2 running Android Version 4.1.1) with adb. I had to change the adb_usb.ini file in .android folder.

Unfortunately, the connection is lost whenever I open eclipse and try to run a project or see if my device is connected by opening the devices tab.

I'm developing on OSX 10.7.5 running Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

(ADB over Wifi works fine with eclipse, but this is not what I'm after)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance you have two different versions of ADB on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

after connection is lost will help?

Comment: No, after connection is lost I have to close Eclipse and force quit adb or even restart my device...